# Too many files open on Mac Neo4J

Tags: macos, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, file-descriptor

Hi I am getting the error for having too many open files with NEo4J.

> 2018-11-28 22:24:06.233+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob]
>   Failed to populate index:
>
> [:MPO_TY(modelId) [provider: {key=lucene+native, version=2.0}]]
>   /opt/neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-3
>
> .4.9/data/databases/graph.db/schema/index/lucene_native-2.0/2001/temporal-1.0/date
>   (Too many open files) |
>
> GB+Tree[file:/opt/neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-3.4.9/data/databases/graph.db/schema/index/lucene_native-2.0/2001/temporal-1.0/date,
>
> layout:DateLayout[version:0.1, identifier:23754265818300416,
>   keySize:16, valueSize:0, fixedSize:true], generation:1/2]
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /opt/neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-3.4.9/data/databases/graph.db/schema/index/lucene_native-2.0/2001/temporal-1.0/date
>   (Too many open files) |
>
> GB+Tree[file:/opt/neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-3.4.9/data/databases/graph.db/schema/index/lucene_native-2.0/2001/temporal-1.0/date,
>
> layout:DateLayout[version:0.1, identifier:23754265818300416,
>   keySize:16, valueSize:0, fixedSize:true], generation:1/2]

As you can see from the path I am using neo4j enterprise 3.4.9 and...

- Spring Boot
- Java 8
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

This is a relatively well documented problem and so far I have tried

1. Adding the -XX:-MaxFDLimit  https://support.structr.com/article/253
2. Changing the environment variable `NEO4J_ULIMIT_NOFILE` https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-set-max-open-files-for-debian-installs/
3. Change the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist` and `limit.maxfiles.plist` files https://gist.github.com/tombigel/d503800a282fcadbee14b537735d202c.  Both of which show it worked when I use `launchctl limit maxfiles` to check.
4. I used `ulimit -n 200000` and `ulimit -u 200000` and placed oth in my .bash_profile
5. I edited `/etc/pam.d/su`

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I ended up doing was to run a docker neo4j container with default args it worked yay. https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/